# Duplicate problems with Selection Sort

Tags: python, sorting, duplicates, selection

If I have a list where all values are unique, the code runs fine. However, if there is a duplicate value within the list, when finding the minimum value for the next iteration, it pulls from the entire list rather than just the remainder of the list.

```
for n in range(0,len(lst)):
    a = min(lst[n:])  #minimum value within remainder of set
    i = lst.index(a)  #index value for minimum value within remainder of set    

    temp = lst[n]
    lst[n] = a
    lst[i] = temp
```

Results look like this:

```
lst = [6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4]

[1, 8, 9, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 9, 6, 8, 4, 7, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 4, 9, 7, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 4, 7, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 5, 4]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 4]
[1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 4, 4]
```

I'm looking for it to return this:

```
[1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `n` is 4, the next minimum is `4` *again*, but `lst.index()` finds the *first* `4` at position 3 instead.

Start searching for the miminum *from `n`*; the `.index()` method takes a second argument `start`, from where to start searching:

```
i = lst.index(a, n)
```

Note that Python can assign to two targets in place, no need to use a temporary intermediate. `range()` with just one argument starts from 0:

```
for n in range(len(lst)):
    a = min(lst[n:])
    i = lst.index(a, n)
    lst[n], lst[i] = a, lst[n]
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [6, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4]
>>> for n in range(0,len(lst)):
...     a = min(lst[n:])
...     i = lst.index(a, n)
...     lst[n], lst[i] = a, lst[n]
... 
>>> lst
[1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the fact that I have the range of the list restricted to [n:] do just that?

Comment: @user2850240: No, you are searching in all of `lst`. You can slice and *then* search; `list[n:].index(a)`, but the second parameter to `.index()` is more efficient.